# Dialogflow conversation / Response recovery from Webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, response, dialogflow-es, data-recovery

[Dialgflow Conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH3OP.jpg) In the conversation history on dialogflow, we don't see the agent's responses from a webhook. Is it possible to recover them?

Comment: That's weird. Is it the same for every intent? You can click on three dots and visit the intent. If the intent is handled by webhook, your webhook must have some issues

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response), the webhook needs to send a response back to the agent. This response is a JSON object that contains the text response and other stuff, so it can be possible that this response is empty somehow. If you set an intent and you write no response you will get something similar, an intent triggered but no message coming back. I suggest checking if everything is alright in the webhook.

Comment: If you're using a GCP Cloud Function/Firebase Function, you can just do `response.send({ fulfillmentText: 'what you want it to say' });`. Otherwise you can use the `dialogflow-fulfillment` NPM package to handle sending that response for you via `webhookClient.add` and `webhookClient.handleRequest`